# I am new to VB (Visual Studio) and I am trying to get the column (2) "LastName" from the Datatable "ClientInfo" in Ascending Order

Tags: vb.net

Below is what I have written and am having trouble figuring out how to send it in Ascending order to the database (in Access) and to retrieve it in Ascending order as well.
I will try to show you my code so that it will be easier to help me.
Is anyone able to help me on this.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Dim IdNum As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection            'THE CONNECTION OBJECT

    Dim dbProvider As String                        'HOLDS THE PROVIDER
    Dim dbSource As String                          'HOLDS THE DATA SOURCE
    Dim MyDocumentsFolder As String                 'HOLDS THE DOCUMENTS FOLDER
    Dim TheDatabase As String                       'HOLDS THE DATABASE NAME
    Dim FullDatabasePath As String                  'HOLDS THE DATABASE PATH

    Dim ds As New DataSet                           'HOLDS A DATASET OBJECT
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter                'HOLDS A DATA_ADAPTER OBJECT
    Dim sql As String                               'HOLDS AN SQL STRING

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'SET UP THE PROVIDER
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"

        'SET THE DATABASE AND WHERE THE DATABASE IS
        TheDatabase = "/ClientInfo.mdb"
        MyDocumentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        FullDatabasePath = MyDocumentsFolder & TheDatabase

        'SET THE DATA SOURCE
        dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

        'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        'OPEN THE DATABASE
        con.Open()

        'STORE THE SQL STRING
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts"

        'PASS THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

        'FILL THE DATASET WITH RECORDS FROM THE DATABASE TABLE
        da.Fill(ds, "ClientInfo")

        'CLOSE THE DATABASE
        con.Close()

        'GET HOW MANY ROWS ARE IN THE DATABASE TABLE
        MaxRows = ds.Tables("ClientInfo").Rows.Count

        'SET A VALUE FOR THE INC VARIABLE
        inc = -1

        'SET A VALUE FOR THE ID NUM VARIABLE
        IdNum = inc + 1001

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

       Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
       Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("ClientInfo").NewRow()

        dsNewRow.Item("FirstName") = txtFirstName.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("LastName") = txtLastName.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("CompanyName") = txtBusName.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Address") = txtAddress.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("City") = txtCity.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("State") = txtState.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Zip") = txtZip.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("HomePh") = txtHomePh.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Mobile") = txtMobile.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("BusinessPh") = txtBusPh.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Ext") = txtExt.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Email") = txtEmail.Text

        ds.Tables("ClientInfo").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        da.Update(ds, "ClientInfo")

        MessageBox.Show("New Record added to the Database")

        Clear()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Order By clause will sort the records returned by the column indicated. The default is ascending but you can add DESC or Descending depending on the database if you want the order reversed.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts Order By LastName;"
```

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your problem is with the query or I don't get you, but if you want to fill the data adapter with the LastName column just use this as a sql query:

```
SELECT LastName FROM tblContacts ORDER BY LastName ASC
```